# Select unexisting values

Tags: php

I have a  database with images which can be tagged.

To tag them I put a value (which represents a color) in a database table called Tagged

**Tagged**

```
  ImgId  (example 5)
  TagId  (example 3)
```

I also have a table called Tags (the colors)

**Tags**

```
  TagId   (example 3)
  Tag     (example blue)
```

In the list with tags are almost 20 tags.

What I have is a page with images so 1 page is imageid 5

if I open the page I want a list of all Tag's from **Tags**

If the TagId is in Tagged it must be like

TagId  Selected

else just

TagId

How can I do this.

I have the database working to tag images but I can't get it to 'see' if the tag is used.

What I have:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM Tags";
        $result = mysql_query("$sql");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        
            echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"color[]\" value=\"".$row['TagId']."\">";
        
        echo $row['TagId'];
        echo "<br>";
      }
```

I guess I need a join or what is the best method?

PS I know I should use mysqli but I use mysql for testing now I adjust it later to mysqli

Comment: see http://whathaveyoutried.com for a nice insight about HOW to ask questions.

Comment: Please post examples of your non-working code/queries, with eventual error messages that you get...

Comment: Updated with an example of what i have so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` with a `GROUP BY` to do one query against the database and get the complete result;

```
SELECT Tag, COUNT(ImgId) selected
FROM TAGS 
LEFT JOIN TAGGED
  ON tags.TagId = TAGGED.TagId
 AND TAGGED.ImgId = 5
GROUP BY Tag;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32288/10).

A short explanation;

I use a `LEFT JOIN` to select all `tags` and all possibly matching entries in `tagged` with `ImgId=5`. If there is no match, the value of `ImgId` is NULL, if there is a match, it's 5. This is a feature of `LEFT JOIN`.

I then count the number of `ImgId`'s per Tag (the COUNT and GROUP BY do that). NULL does not count, so the count becomes 0, while 5 counts and gives the count 1 (remember, we restricted to hits only on a single ImgId, 5).

Comment: Can you explain what you do here i get you first select Tag and then count if it is tagged if tagged 1 else 0,is ' AND TAGGED.ImgId =5'  is equal to WHERE TAGGED.ImgId =5?

Comment: @SvenB Added a short explanation, putting an `AND` inside the `LEFT JOIN` is not the same thing as a `WHERE`. The `WHERE` will filter rows away entirely, while an AND inside a `LEFT JOIN` will return the value from the left table, and set all columns from the rightmost table to NULL if there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$sqlTagged = "SELECT TagId
    FROM Tagged WHERE ImgId=".$YouImgId;
$result = mysql_query($sqlTagged);
$arrTagged = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $arrTagged[] = $row["TagId"];
}
$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM Tags";
$result = mysql_query("$sql");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $selected = (in_array($row['TagId'],$arrTagged) ? "checked='checked'" : "";
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"color[]\"  ".$selected." value=\"".$row['TagId']."\">";

  }
```